# Como inserto formulas matematicas en html?

Tags: javascript, html

quisiera saber si alguien me puede ayudar con esto.
Quiero agregar formulas matematicas a html. COn un boton,
ejemplo: al precionar divicion que me aparesca un recuadro arriba la raya de la divicion y el numero que esta en la parte de abajo. Tambien para poder escribir integrales mediante botones.

No quiero que me arrojen resultados, solo que pueda escribir formulas matematicas.
De antemano gracias

Comment: Tu publicación no se ajusta a [ask] y por ende terminaría cerrada

Comment: No todos lo navegadores lo soportan, pero [MathML](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML) puede ser una opción con FireFox y Safari.

Comment: Si no los soportan todos los navegadores, como es que la pagina de simbolab funciona en todos los navegadores? Es a lo que me refiero para ser mas exacto, hacer una pagina similar a esa, pero no quiero que me arroje resultados, solo que tenga la capacidad de escribir formulas matematicas

Comment: si manejas la sintaxis de latex proba https://latex.js.org/ no es muy compleja podes practicar aquí https://latexeditor.lagrida.com/

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza [MathJax](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/index.html) para soportar cualquier navegador. Simplemente agrega los scripts en tu página. Por ejemplo:

```js
let input = document.querySelector("input")
let p = document.querySelector("p")
function addEquation() {
    MathJax.typesetPromise().then(() => {
        p.innerHTML = `\\[ ${input.value} \\]` + p.innerHTML;
        MathJax.typesetPromise();
    })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>


<input type="text" value="x^2 + y^2 = 1">
<button onClick="addEquation()">Agregar Ecuación</button>

<p>
  Cuando \(a \ne 0\), hay dos soluciones a la ecuación \(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\) y están dadas por:
  \[x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.\]
  
   Algunos ejemplos de integrales:
  
  $$\int x^2 \, dx = \frac{x^3}3 +C$$
  
  $$\iint r(\cos\varphi+\sin\varphi)\,d\varphi\,dr$$
</p>
```

Comment: me sirvio mucho tu ayuda. gracias. Ahora como le hago para que los datos los pueda ingresar el usuario con su teclado.  pense que que seria con un input text pero no me funciono. por ejemplo: \[
x^{ 2 }+y^{2}=r^{2}
\] esa formula. queria sustituirla asi x^{ <input type="text" }+y^{2}=r^{2}
\] pero no funciona. Hay algun metodo de hacerlo?

Comment: @Juanhuerta ahí te agregué como agregar ecuaciones desde un input.

Comment: me marca este error al ejecutarlo Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')
    at meta.html:11:38 , pero cuando le doy clic en ejecutar a tu codigo no marca nada de error, en que estare mal?

Comment: @Juanhuerta Si pruebas el código acá te darás cuenta que funciona. Algo habrás tecleado mal. Ni siquiera has aceptado mi respuesta, así que no vale la pena que pierda mi tiempo ayudándote con tus errores. ¡Muy buena suerte!

Comment: soy nuevo amigo, no se como aceptar las respuestas, pense que se publicaban automaticamente.